# Java Generics to return Enum based on value

Tags: java, generics, enums, java-8

I have number of Enums that share the method across them. I would like to move it to an interface if possible so I don't have to duplicate it and the code would look a lot cleaner. But after much effort I am still unable to move the methods to an interface.

```
public enum TypeA {
    ValueAA ("Value AA"),
    ValueAB ("Value AB");

    private final String type;

    TypeA (final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeA fromValue(final String value) {
        for (TypeA t : TypeA.values()) {
            if (t.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder allTypes = new StringBuilder();
        boolean bFirstTime = true;
        for (TypeA val : TypeA.values()) {
            allTypes.append(bFirstTime ? "" : ", ").append(val);
            bFirstTime = false;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is an invalid value. Supported values are " + allTypes);
    }
}

public enum TypeB {
    ValueBA ("Value BA"),
    ValueBB ("Value BB");

    private final String type;

    TypeB (final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeB fromValue(final String value) {
        for (TypeB t : TypeB.values()) {
            if (t.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder allTypes = new StringBuilder();
        boolean bFirstTime = true;
        for (TypeB val : TypeB.values()) {
            allTypes.append(bFirstTime ? "" : ", ").append(val);
            bFirstTime = false;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is an invalid value. Supported values are " + allTypes);
    }
}
```

Using Generics and Java 8 is there anyway to move `getType` and `fromValue` methods to an interface so that I can share across all the Enums ? Also note the Jackson annotations `JsonValue` & `JsonCreator`.

Comment: You actually need state and state requires classes. Enum types cannot be subtypes of your own classes.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation

Comment: You could maybe create an auxiliary class to hold state and share an instance between other classes. It seems likely, however, that enums are not what you want. You could roll your own type-safe enumeration and give them common code, or better, create a state-maintaining class that holds the desired state and also holds enum values. It's unclear what is best for you because your example gives no hint as to why you need enums, let alone two kinds that share state. On the face you likely don't, and should instead rethink your model.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: this state is invariant and interfaces support constants. So in this specific case, it is possible. But I’d keep the `getType` method conventionally in the `enum` types though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `fromValue` implementation to an `interface`, however, I suppose, you have to keep stubs in the concrete types for supporting the JSON factory annotation:

```
interface TypeX {
    String getType();
    static <T extends Enum<T>&TypeX> T fromValue(String value, Class<T> type) {
        EnumSet<T> all=EnumSet.allOf(type);
        for (T t: all) {
            if (t.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(all.stream().map(t -> t.getType())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ",
                value+" is an invalid value. Supported values are ", "")));
    }
}

public enum TypeA implements TypeX {
    ValueAA ("Value AA"),
    ValueAB ("Value AB");

    private final String type;

    TypeA (final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeA fromValue(final String value) {
        return TypeX.fromValue(value, TypeA.class);
    }
}

enum TypeB implements TypeX {
    ValueBA ("Value BA"),
    ValueBB ("Value BB");

    private final String type;

    TypeB (final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeB fromValue(final String value) {
        return TypeX.fromValue(value, TypeB.class);
    }
}
```

For completeness, since the type property is invariant, it is possible to move the `getType` method to the `interface`, if we use a different implementation:

```
interface TypeX {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @interface Type { String value(); }

    @JsonValue default String getType() {
        for(Field f: getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredFields()) try {
            if(f.isEnumConstant() && f.get(null)==this) {
                return f.getAnnotation(Type.class).value();
            }
        } catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    Class<? extends TypeX> getDeclaringClass();

    static <T extends Enum<T>&TypeX> T fromValue(String value, Class<T> type) {
        EnumSet<T> all=EnumSet.allOf(type);
        for (T t: all) {
            if (t.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(all.stream().map(t -> t.getType())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ",
                value+" is an invalid value. Supported values are ", "")));
    }
}

public enum TypeA implements TypeX {
    @Type("Value AA") ValueAA,
    @Type("Value AB") ValueAB;

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeA fromValue(final String value) {
        return TypeX.fromValue(value, TypeA.class);
    }
}

enum TypeB implements TypeX {
    @Type("Value BA") ValueBA,
    @Type("Value BB") ValueBB;

    @JsonCreator
    public static TypeB fromValue(final String value) {
        return TypeX.fromValue(value, TypeB.class);
    }
}
```

But this has several drawbacks, e.g. the Reflection based access is not checked at compile-time and may have performance disadvantages at runtime. And I don’t know whether the `@JsonValue` will be respected the intended way when appearing at a `default` method inherited from an `interface`.

Comment: Why would you use the likes of `TypeA.class` instead of `values()`?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: `TypeA.class` is a single cheap bytecode instruction, `values()` is a method invocation whereas the invoked method creates and populates a new array. So it should come natural to make the caller side a cheap operation and let `fromValue` encapsulate the way it works, i.e. `EnumSet.allOf(…)` does *not* create an array. `fromValue` might even implement caching a map from `String` value to `enum` constant without any changes on the caller side. Passing in an array would be counterproductive.

Comment: I think the presumed cost of a method invocation is going to be irrelevant compared to all the stuff you are doing to avoid it. And the code...

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: I’m not doing *anything* “to avoid it”. If you want to use `values()` instead of `EnumSet.allOf`, you only have to replace `EnumSet<T>` with `T[]`, without changing anything of program logic. There is still no reason why every caller should do that operation, instead of having the single method taking care of it.